# How can I select my object from database, if it have constructor with attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Let's assume we have a class named Fruit. And this class has two attributes, a construct, methods getters and setters, and finally, one method to save the information and other to select the object based on your id.

Note:
Table structure

CREATE TABLE TB_FRUIT (
    ID_FRUIT int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME_FRUIT varchar(255),
    COLOR_FRUIT varchar(255)
);

e.g

```
class Fruit {
```

```
// Properties
```

```
    public $name;
    public $color;
```

```
// Fruit Construct
```

```
    public function __construct($name, $color)
    {
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setColor($color);
    }
```

```
// Methods
```

```
    public function setName($name) {
      $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName() {
      return $this->name;
    }
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
    public function setColor($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }
```

```
//Save Fruit on database
```

```
    public function saveDB($conn)
    {
        $name = $this->getName();
        $color = $this->getColor();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TB_FRUIT(
                NAME_FRUIT,
                COLOR_FRUIT
                )
                VALUES("
            . "$name"
            . "$color";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            $msg = 'Success';
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
```

//Select Fruit on database

```
    public function selectDB($conn, $id_fruit)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM TB_FRUIT WHERE ID_FRUIT = '$id_fruit'";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            $msg = 'Success';
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }


} //end class
```

We need save on database and after we need select by id, but we doesn't have any other information about the fruit, only your id.

How can I select my object from database, if it have constructor with attributes?

I mean, when we'll select on database, we doesn't know the object attributes. We only know the object id.

Comment: You will need to distinguish between when the object is being created, and when the object is being retrieved from the database. When being retrieved from the database, as per a given "FRUIT_ID", then fetch the ROW for that ID, then set the attributes of the object to the COLUMNS of the fetched ROW.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.